# How to make a specific region use a specific template?

Tags: theming

I'm currently working on Drupal 7 project in a Zen sub-theme. Each of my region uses "region.tpl.php" as HTML/PHP template. I just created a new region called "foo". This region needs a different HTML/PHP than the other regions.

**How do I make Drupal use my custom template "region--foo.tpl.php" instead of the default "region.tpl.php"?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought Drupal already added the theme hook suggestion for region--name.tpl.php, but if not you can add it yourself with a preprocess function in your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__' . $vars['region'];
}
```

Once you clear Drupal's caches your new template file should start being used for that region. It might be worth noting that you'll probably need a copy of the core region.tpl.php file somewhere in your theme folder as well, or the theme registry might not pick up your custom file.

Comment: I'm not succeeding. I added the region "foo". I populated it with blocks. I copied "region--tpl.php", added extra code and renamed that file to region--foo.tpl.php. Then in template.php I added "function aura_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__foo' . $vars['foo'];
}" and no modules are shown... What did I forget?

Comment: @Apex I think you've added rather than forgotten :) The `$vars['region']` variable will already have `foo` in it so that line should literally be: `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__' . $vars['region'];`

Comment: Ok succes! I forgot to add "<?php print render($page['foo']); ?>" in page.tpl.php. So if I get this right, if region--foo.tpl.php exists it will overwrite region.tpl.php? If region--foo.tpl.php does not exists it simply uses region.tpl.php?

Comment: Yep, spot on :)

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. Also by removing the Zen theme's default region--footer.tpl.php the footer region finally gets the standard region template (region.tpl.php). Have been looking for that for quiet a while. Thanks a lot Clive, appreciate your help.